# Airflow and Templates reference and PostgresHook

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I have a question
I want to use Templates reference - {{ds}}
When substituting in PostgresOperator, everything works out well (I guess so)
And PostgresHook does not want to work

```
 def prc_mymys_update(procedure: str, type_agg: str):
    with PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID_GP).get_conn() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            with open(URL_YML_2,"r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                ya_2 = yaml.safe_load(f)
                yml_mymts_2 = ya_2['type_agg']
                query_pg = ""
                if yml_mymts_2[0]['type_agg_name'] == "day" and type_agg == "day":
                    sql_1 = yml_mymts_2[0]['sql']
                    query_pg = f"""{sql_1}"""
                elif yml_mymts_2[1]['type_agg_name'] == "retention" and type_agg == "retention":
                    sql_2 = yml_mymts_2[1]['sql']
                    query_pg = f"""{sql_2}"""
                elif yml_mymts_2[2]['type_agg_name'] == "mau" and type_agg == "mau":
                    sql_3 = yml_mymts_2[2]['sql']
                    query_pg = f"""{sql_3}"""
                cur.execute(query_pg)
                dates_list = cur.fetchall()
                for date_res in dates_list:
                    cur.execute(
                        "select from {}(%(date)s::date);".format(procedure),
                        {"date": date_res[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},
                    )
    conn.close()
```

I use yml

```
type_agg:
  - type_agg_name: day
    sql: select calendar_date from entertainment_dds.v_calendar where calendar_date between '{{ds}}'::date - interval '7 days' and '{{ds}}'::date - 1 order by 1 desc
  - type_agg_name: retention
    sql: SELECT t.date::date AS date FROM generate_series((date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date) - interval '11 month'), date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date) , '1 month'::interval) t(date) order by 1 asc
  - type_agg_name: mau
    sql: select dt::date date_ from generate_series('{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date - interval '7 days', '{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date - interval '1 days', interval '1 days') dt order by 1 asc
```

And when I run a dag, it comes to a moment with a certain task that uses

```
- type_agg_name: retention
    sql: SELECT t.date::date AS date FROM generate_series((date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date) - interval '11 month'), date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date) , '1 month'::interval) t(date) order by 1 asc
```

I have wrong

psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "y" does not exist
LINE 1: ...((date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgkzj.png)

I tried to find information on the interaction of Templates reference and PostgresHook, but found nothing

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-reference

Answer (score 0):

Note the single quotes in the following query:

```
sql: SELECT t.date::date AS date FROM generate_series((date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date) - interval '11 month'), date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date) , '1 month'::interval) t(date) order by 1 asc
```

Specifically, this part:

```
'{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'
```

You have two separate strings here, separated by the date format. Here's the first string:

```
'{{execution_date.strftime('
```

This causes the date format to be rendered separately. If you wrap the date format in double quotes instead of single quotes, it should resolve this error. For example:

```
sql: SELECT t.date::date AS date FROM generate_series((date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}'::date) - interval '11 month'), date_trunc('month','{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'::date) , '1 month'::interval) t(date) order by 1 asc
```

---

Note that you might need to swap the double and single quotes if double quotes in the RDBMS are used for other purposes, for example:

```
"{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. `templated_fields` is an [attribute of the `BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/23da4daaa018e72b39b977afcde85deaf2224f1e/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L611) in Airflow from which all operators inherit. This is which passing in a Jinja expression when using the [`PostgresOperator`](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/postgres/modules/postgresoperator%5D) works just fine.

If you need to write a custom task, you need to render the template values explicitly. Like this, untested, but I'm sure this can be extrapolated in your function:

```py
def prc_mymys_update(procedure: str, type_agg: str, ti):
    ti.render_templates()

    with PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID_GP).get_conn() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            ...
```

The `ti` kwargs represents the Airflow Task Instance and is directly accessible as part of the execution context pushed to every task in Airflow. That object has a [`render_templates()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/23da4daaa018e72b39b977afcde85deaf2224f1e/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L2129) which will translate the Jinja expression to a value.

If the `PostgresOperator` doesn't fit your needs you can always subclass the operator and tailor it accordingly.

Also, the `sql` string itself has single quotes which cause string parsing issues as you're seeing:
`'{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}'`
Should be something like:
`'{{execution_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}'`